# Export activities and the activity target contact

Tags: export, activity

I found an old thread on the forum site: -
 https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=20506.0

My question is still the same as DaveJ's actually. We want to export the **activity target contact** with the activity details.

By default, it is exporting the activity source contact

Comment: Can't really offer an answer, but if 'export' from a search isn't giving you the fields you need, can you get closer via an export from a civi Report, or if you are using Drupal I am certain you can do it via a View.

Answer (score 1):

I think petednz's comment is a good one - but you can also use the Activity Report from the Reports menu.